# Config module not found when running Flask in Spyder

Tags: python, flask, spyder

I'm going through the [Flask mega-tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) with the following project structure

```
my-project/
   app/
      __init__.py
      routes.py
   config.py
```

With my `__init__.py` file :

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

from app import routes
```

While running `__init__.py` from Spyder, I had the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

I'm new to Flask and Python, and the problem must be that python, run from Spyder, doesn't find the `config.py` file in the top-level directory. Would you have any recommendations on how to setup Spyder or structure my project? Thank you

ps : the project ran fine when running `Flask run` from the command line, but I'd like to use Spyder for debug functionalities

Comment: You don't _run_ `__init__.py__`. You're not really following the tutorial because `config.py` doesn't [appear until Lesson 4](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/tree/v0.4) and you're missing the equivalent of [`microblog.py`](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/blob/v0.4/microblog.py) which is the entry-point to the app - that's the file you run after setting the appropriate environment vars. Not `__init__.py`. You need to backtrack because you've missed quite a few steps

Comment: @roganjosh. I'm already at Step 5, and this is where I wanted to continue the tutorial in Spyder. I trimmed some details in my question. But you're right, I misplaced `microblog.py`and `.flaskenv` (I placed them in /app). I moved them, opened `microblog.py` in Spyder and ran it. This time I got no error, but the program seems to have stopped immediatly on the IPython console (I have nothing on `localhost:5000`). I also downloaded the whole [git project](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog), and I had the same behavior :( is there an additional env var I should set for my environment?

Comment: _don't_ run your app through Spyder (I develop primarily in Spyder and still run my app externally in a cmd/powershell/terminal). It's just more hassle than it's worth. You're not that far in; I'd honestly suggest ditching the current base and start again (you're talking a couple of hours, tops, to get it right)

Comment: Oh thanks for the advice :) I'll do that in this case, and I'll check flask debug functionalities. Thanks!